# How to remove extra white space between div rows and make all div images square size?

Tags: html, css

I have created the following page for ios devices when I display the page on iPhone I get extra white space at the bottom of each row! I don't know how to remove the extra white space between each rows(there is 3 images in each row) and how to make all images be of same size(square size)I would appreciate if you guys help me.Thanks

[image]

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #003569
}

.images .line {
  margin-bottom: 14vw;
  margin-left: 2vw;
  margin-right: 2vw;
  display: flex
}

.images .line .img {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 47vw;
  height: 47vw;
  margin-right: 1vw
}

.images .line .img .img-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff
}

.images .line .img .img-wrap:hover .desc {
  transform: translateY(0)
}

.images .line .img img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0
}

.images .line .img .icon {
  display: none
}

.images .line .img .download {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -46px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #555;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: .5px .5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.images .line .img .video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(./img/icon1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1000
}

.images .line .img .Carousel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(./img/icon2.png);
  #background-size: cover;
  background-size: 65px 65px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  z-index: 1000
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="images">

  <div class="line">


    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/a" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>


    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/b" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt=""><div class="video"></div></a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>


    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/c" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt=""><div class="video"></div></a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>
  </div>


  <div class="line">
    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/d" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt=""><div class="Carousel"></div></a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>


    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/e" target="_blank">
        <i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="Carousel"></div>
      </a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>


    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/f" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt=""><div class="Carousel"></div></a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a>
    </div>


  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: are you wanting all the images to be square (they are currently rectangular)

Comment: Thanks for replies. Yes i want all the images be square and no margin on side of each rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for the rows, padding top trick to make squares and object-fit to make your images fit the squares (you will need a polyfill for ie if you use object fit - otherwise you can replace the images with background images if you do not want to use object fit)

I have left the icons and download links for you to style

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #003569
}


/* try not to over qualify selectors - it's inefficient and harder to maintain. if you have many line classes doing different things, then you need to use something more specific to this line - eg image-line */

.line {
  margin: 2vw 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* spaces out images evenly with no space at the sides */
}

.img {
  flex-basis: 32%; /* allow for 3 images per line with 2% space between each image */
  max-width: 32%;  
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* creates a square */
}

.img-wrap>img {
  /* make img fill link */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* make image fill square and keep aspect ratio */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="images">

  <!-- try indenting your code properly - helps with maintenance and just makes things easier to read and see where the nesting levels are -->

  <div class="line">
    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/a" target="_blank">
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/b" target="_blank">
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="video"></div>
      </a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/c" target="_blank">
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="video"></div>
      </a>
      <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="line">
    <div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/d" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt=""><div class="Carousel"></div></a><a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')"
        download="">Download</a></div>
    <div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/e" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" alt=""><div class="Carousel"></div></a><a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')"
        download="">Download</a></div>
    <div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/f" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt=""><div class="Carousel"></div></a><a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')"
        download="">Download</a></div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Useful Links:

- [Flexbox playground (codepen)](http://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv)
- [Object fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)
- [Padding top trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)

Comment: Many thanks that fixed the spacing issue. Could you tell me how to decrease the space between images and no space at all on right and left side of each row ?

Comment: Sorry the space either side of the line is caused by the margin - you had 2vw on your original - just remove that (and add what margin bottom you want).  To reduce the gap between images, you need to increase the size of the img - you can change the max-width and basis from 30% up to 33 and a third percent - see edit

Comment: I reduced the space between images from 30% to 33% and it reduced the space between each image but when i removed  margin: 2vw 0; it did not remove the space on both side of each row !

Comment: Then something else in your code is causing it - as you can see above has no space either side of the images, please create a fidldle or ask a new question showing the error as there is nothing I can do without seeing what is causing it

Comment: I found the problem. I am using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"> for my page. Is there a way to keep this meta tag and have no space on each side of row?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would add spacing either side of the line, perhaps you need to ask a new question as this one has been answered

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
margin-bottom: 14vw;
```

From your .images .line {}  css rule

Margin and Padding cause white space. The easiest way to see what css rules are causing the margin or padding is with Chrome dev tools

Also you are setting the height of all images to 47vh. Change it to something like 27vh.

```
  .images .line .img {
      width: 47vw;
      height: 27vw;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried that before i post here and that didn't remove the extra white space between rows

Comment: The massive white space you show in your img is definitely the 14vw. The only other margin-bottom you have is 10px which is to small. Did you refresh your browser and clear your cache?

Comment: See my update and here https://codepen.io/GifCo/pen/oVMRbz?editors=1111

Comment: I made all the changes you suggested and it decreased the white space a little but the download buttons for first row is not visible now.(I am testing and making the code on iphone 7 plus view not desktop!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change heigh of this class

```
.images .line .img {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 47vw;
    height: 22vw;
    margin-right: 1vw

}
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #003569
}



.images .line {
    margin-bottom: 14vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-right: 2vw;
    display: flex
}

.images .line .img {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 47vw;
    height: 22vw;
    margin-right: 1vw

}

.images .line .img .img-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff
}

.images .line .img .img-wrap:hover .desc {
    transform: translateY(0)
}

.images .line .img img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0
}

.images .line .img .icon {
    display: none
}

.images .line .img .download {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -46px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    color: #555;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    box-shadow: .5px .5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.images .line .img .video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(./img/icon1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1000
}

.images .line .img .Carousel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(./img/icon2.png);
    #background-size: cover;
    background-size: 65px 65px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    z-index: 1000

}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">


<style>




</style>


</head>

<body>


<br><br>

<div id="myDiv" class="images">

<div class="line">
    <div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/a" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt=""></a>                         <a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>
<div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/b" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt=""><div class="video"></div></a><a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>
  <div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/c" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt=""><div class="video"></div></a><a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>
</div>


<div class="line">
    <div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/d" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt=""><div class="Carousel"></div></a><a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>
<div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/e" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" alt=""><div class="Carousel"></div></a><a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>
  <div class="img"><a class="img-wrap" href="https://awebsite.com/n/f" target="_blank"><i class="icon"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt=""><div class="Carousel"></div></a><a class="download" href="https://" onclick="ma('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')" download="">Download</a></div>
</div>


</div>


</body>
```